# How to access url attr of media:thumbnail and media:content elements in RSS Feed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rss

I am attempting to consume my Zenfolio RSS feed so that i can display the images in the feed. How can i access the url value of the media:thumbnail and media:content elements in my RSS feed? I have googled high and low and not found an answer regarding how to access the url value. There was a similiar unanswered [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929314/how-to-read-a-image-url-from-a-rss-with-syndicationfeed).

Examples of the elements:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://riderdesign.net/img/s11/v35/p449020235-2.jpg" 
                     width="400"
                     height="225"
        />
  <media:content url="http://riderdesign.net/img/s11/v35/p449020235-2.jpg"
                   type="image/jpeg" medium="image"
                   width="400"
                   height="225"
        />
```

My code in my controller:

```
  Public Function Feed() As ActionResult
            Dim feedurl As String = "http://riderdesign.net/recent.rss"
            Using x = XmlReader.Create(feedurl)
                Dim r As SyndicationFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(x)
                Return View(r)
            End Using
        End Function
```

In my view i have @ModelType System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed and

```
@For Each i In ViewData.Model.Items
    @i.Title.text  @<br /> 
    <!--What do i do here to get the url values?-->
Next
```

Comment: Can you use XPath or WCF's RSS object to parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my solution. I'll post code here in a bit.

Code:

```
     Public Function Feed() As ActionResult
        Dim feedurl As String = "http://riderdesign.net/p319394411/recent.rss"
        Using x = XmlReader.Create(feedurl)
            Dim r = XDocument.Load(x)
            Dim mediapfx As XNamespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"

            Dim ml = From item In r.Descendants(mediapfx + "content") Select item
            Dim medialist = From item In r.Descendants("item") Select New MediaImage With {
             .Id = item.Element("guid").Value, .ImageUrl = TryGetAttributeValue(item.Element(mediapfx + "content"), "url")} Take 5
            Return View(medialist)

        End Using

    End Function

    Private Function TryGetAttributeValue(ByVal xe As XElement, ByVal attribute As String) As String
        If xe IsNot Nothing AndAlso xe.Attribute(attribute) IsNot Nothing Then
            Return xe.Attribute(attribute).Value
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function



Namespace RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.ViewModels
    Public Class MediaImage

        Public Property Id() As String

        Public Property ImageUrl() As String

    End Class
End Namespace
```

In view:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.ViewModels.MediaImage)

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Feed"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout4.vbhtml"
End Code

<h2>Feed</h2>
@For Each i In Model
    @<img src=" @i.ImageUrl" />

Next
```